# is there any solution to directly write in servlet response?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

i use java with spring framework. java has a good library, POI which creates xlsx file.

it does not depends on some code.
i have a question write it into the servlet response while server make xlsx.

but i give you example. the code is rough because i'm developing.

```
public void buildXlsx(HttpServletRequest 
request,HttpServletResponse response) throws 
Exception {

response.setHeader("Content-Description", "File Transfer");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 
"attachment;filename=justAFile.xlsx");
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
response.setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

try (SXSSFWorkbook xlsWriter1 = new SXSSFWorkbook()) {
    SXSSFSheet sheet1 = xlsWriter1.createSheet("sheet");

    Font defaultFont1 = xlsWriter1.createFont();

    defaultFont1.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);

    CellStyle headStyle1 = xlsWriter1.createCellStyle();
    headStyle1.setFont(defaultFont1);

    CellStyle bodyStyle1 = xlsWriter1.createCellStyle();
    bodyStyle1.setFont(defaultFont1);

    Row row1 = null;
    Cell cell1 = null;
    int rowNo1 = 0;
    int headerColNo1 = 0;
    row1 = sheet1.createRow(rowNo1++);

    cell1 = row1.createCell(headerColNo1++);
    cell1.setCellValue("sdf dd");
    cell1.setCellStyle(headStyle1);


    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

        row1 = sheet1.createRow(rowNo1++);
        cell1 = row1.createCell(i);
        cell1.setCellValue("i don't know " + i);
        cell1.setCellStyle(bodyStyle1);
        xlsWriter1.write(response.getOutputStream()); // no way, write only once. how to perform lazy generate?
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

that has process like creating xlsx form -> make temp file -> flush response .
that makes huge waiting response time while file transfer into response.

but that cannot implement this creating xlsx form -> flush response.

this means it keeps connection and sends partial data continuously. Like youTube streaming.

nodeJs can do this with excelJs as I know.
but they haven't managed issues nowadays(https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/209).

and someone has the solution(https://d2.naver.com/helloworld/9423440, how?)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You're trying to send the same Workbook 10000 times to the client? Certainly not what the response headers say. And as you `sleep` for 100ms each loop iteration, you're effectively sleepint for 1000 seconds - no wonder, this takes a while to finish...

Comment: data is huge  over 1m. if  it makes temp file, response body causes server response timeout.    yes.  no one answered the question.   you're right, this code is not right. but it says  'i want to  go  to the client  with buffering!'. my goal is mimic streaming transfer.

Comment: So basically you want to write the stream over and over to the client each time with new data?

Comment: exactly, right. POI doesn't offer it. there's no java xlsx library for network transfer.

Comment: yes, it is hard or maybe impossible. but uploaded this link(https://d2.naver.com/helloworld/9423440) shows it possible.  is it true or trick?  this is the first step and can close similary questions which continues since few years ago

Comment: DeferredSXSSFWorkbook is an experimental variant of SXSSFWorkbook that is meant to produce a better solution when writing to response streams - see https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/streaming/DeferredGeneration.java

Comment: The most robust solution is an async API. The request message contains a URL and you respond that you've received the request. A background thread generates the xlsx and posts it to request URL when it is ready.

Comment: wow, it works well. I can adopt it in my service!  thank you very much.